# Routing inside subcomponents not working while using 'exact' : ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I have created one simple project with 3 main components/pages.

1. Home page (path: "/") with is login page. once we click on login button, will create a dynamic URL "*admin/random_num*
   **LogIn.js**

```
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "../Admin/Dashboard";

export default function Login(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login form</h1>
      <Link to={`/admin/${Math.random()}`}>Login Button</Link>
      <Route path="/admin/:aid" component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

2nd component/page is admin(path: "/admin/randum_num" , eg: "/admin/132"), which should be displayed when clicked on  login button on login page.
**Admin.js**

```
export default function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

3rd component is 404page, which will simply display when no route is matched.
**Error404.js**

```
export default function Error404() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>404</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

last not the least, in App.js i am setting up routing.
**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Error404 from './pages/Error404';
import Login from './pages/StartingScreen/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route  component={Error404} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note**: i am able to display the admin dashboard page if i remove "exact" parameter in Route statement but after removing "exact" both Login and Dashboard page will be visible which i dont want. I want only one component should be visible at given route.

I am struggling to find an answer regarding this problem since one week, kindly help. If the given detail is incomplete, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `exact` for your login component, that means your `Login` component will only render for the root path `/`.

And your `Dashboard` component is inside your `Login` component, that means you also need to add `"/admin/:aid"` to your login route.

You need to change this

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
```

to

```
<Route exact path={["/", "/admin/:aid"]} component={Login} />
```

**Update:**
To hide login button, you can use another `Switch` in your `Login` component

```
export default function Login(props) {
  return (
    <div>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <h1>Login form</h1>
          <Link to={`/admin/${Math.random()}`}>Login Button</Link>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin/:aid" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi sohaib!! Thanks for answering but alas its not working as expected.  After following your syntax. I am able to go "Dashboard" component but still "Login" Component login button is also visible. Thus, its behavior is same as before if I dont put "exact" in Route statement.

Comment: This wasn't part of your question. Anyway, I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you much. I was struggling since one week. I want to cast  a vote but my reputation level is only 11 hence, I cant vote. Sorry about that.